# Cannot load Admob ANE in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I tried to use admob ANE from this link:

https://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios-and-android/

Followed the instructions, load up the ane file and put the code :

```
var admob:Admob=Admob.getInstance();//create a instance
admob.setKeys("a152834c2b8cce6");//set admob appid
admob.showBanner(Admob.BANNER,AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);//show banner with relation position
```

but it seem that flash cannot load the ane properly. Error :

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 6', Frame 1, Line 15  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Admob.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 6', Frame 1, Line 15  1120: Access of undefined property Admob.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 6', Frame 1, Line 17  1120: Access of undefined property Admob.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 6', Frame 1, Line 17  1120: Access of undefined property AdPosition.
```

Im using flash cs6 with air sdk 4.0, am i missing anything?

Comment: Have you imported (added) ANE.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you import the ane

```
import so.cuo.platform.admob.Admob;
import so.cuo.platform.admob.AdmobPosition;
```

also link the ane in cs6 by clicking actionscript 3 settings and choose the .ane file

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 6', Frame 1, Line 21 1120: Access of undefined property AdPosition.

Comment: import seems to work with admob var, still adPosition undefined. i tried to import with import so.cuo.platform.admob.*; still not found.

Comment: Need to change AdPosition to AdmobPosition, i had same problem

Answer (score 1):

I saw the doc https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash ,find you have a error in the code.

```
var admob:Admob=Admob.getInstance();
admob.setKeys("a152834c2b8cce6");
admob.showBanner(Admob.BANNER,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

but your code is

```
admob.showBanner(Admob.BANNER,AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);//show banner with relation position
```

you need change AdPosition  to AdmobPosition

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add `ANE` from the highlighted button.

[image]

Comment: Make sure if it is iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

I did have exactly the same problem with
so.cuo.platform.admob.Admob

And i lot of time to make it work.

When i manage to integrate it the app was refused since the library is obsolete.

I then found this other ANE extension which seems a lot more complete:
- https://github.com/lancelot1/ane-admob

This did work at first try also in CS6, and the app did pass the approval.

The ad in the app are now working flawless!

Strongly suggested if you still have issue, or if you wish to switch on a more advance extension.